# How can I modify my webpack project to reference itself from a discreet location, rather than from a relative path?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am working on a small React project that is built and then pulled into a larger application.  To be clear, I have no rights or authority to change what I'm about to outline.  The application builds and deploys as it does, and I can't change how my project fits into the larger application that it is a part of.  However, I might be able to make minor improvements to our build steps that prep our project for integration into the parent application.

My teams React project is a CRA project that is built with webpack.  Once the application is built, the webpack-built CSS & JS files are stored and hosted in Azure.  After that portion of the deployment is done, another application builds a `load.js` file, which is referenced and used in the main React applications `index.html`, to pull in our code.  To further clarify, our files are hosted from an Azure server that has a different domain than the main application.

At some point in the process of setting up our small project to work with in the main React application, an error was found in the `main.[hash].js` file which was preventing it from working properly.  Specifically, there is a problem with the following line:

```
u.src=e.p+"static/js/"+({}[t]||t)+"."+{0:"bc79965c"}[t]+".chunk.js";
```

In order to get our application to work in dev (and eventually production) we have had to create a deployment step that searches the `main.[hash].js` file for `"u.src=e.p"` and replaces it with "`u.src={insert the root of our hosted project files from Azure}"`.

Today, however, I further inspected the `main...js` code to try to figure out the point of the `e.p` variable.  I noticed that webpack is defining `e.p` as simply "/", or the expected root of the project. The offending code is trying to get a value for root, so that it can find the respective `chunk.js` file that should pair with the `main.js` file.  In our case, `chunk.js` isn't in the root folder because neither it or our main file are hosted in the static folder of the parent React project.

My question is simple-- within a webpack (or other) config file, is there some way I can specify what the root path should be considered to be when building these files?  Specifically, is there a way to override which value is stored in the minified `e.p` value of our `main...js` file outputted by webpack so that it provides a fully qualified URL that I can specify?

Also, I'll spare the long explanation but outputting our application in an `<iframe />` block isn't feasible.  That's not a plausible solution in our context.

**NOTES REGARDING Murilo Cruz ANSWER**

I was already aware of the `"homepage": "http://www.myhomepage.com/relativePath"` property but that's not the solution.  This is used to add a relative path to the process.  To be sure, I attempted to add our web address to the `homepage` package property and it did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is [a section on the documentation](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment#building-for-relative-paths) that specifies how to build your create-react-app project exacty as you said.

You just have to add a property on your `package.json` of your create-react-app project root:

```
"homepage": "http://mywebsite.com/relativepath",
```

Comment: That's not quite what I'm looking for.  The base URL for these hosted files are completely different than the final output.  For instance, our primary app might be on "http://www.foo.com" but these files will be hosted in "http://bar.com/tools".  This means I need the reference to these files to be fully qualified.